# curl error SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: nginx, curl

Running the command `curl -v https://myhost`, curl shows the error `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to IP:PORT`

What might be the root issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was not with curl or the host curl was running on, but with the webserver, nginx which I was curling.

TLS was not properly configured in the web server, which resulted in the curl error. The fix for my server was to add the required lines `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key`.

In `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;   # <-- this line was missing
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem; # <-- this line was missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was with my router. I have a PPPoE Internet connection and the MTU size is less then the default 1500. So what I had to do is set a firewall rule about mss clamping in ther router:

```
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

more info about this issue [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html)